# Why did Cora say this after their intimate scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, frankie-and-johnny

After Johnny and Cora have sex, Johnny was grateful because she did the woman astride position, but Cora didn't get that that was woman astride position (woman being on top), and she said

> "What, you mean on top?"

What makes her think that what she's doing isn't woman astride position?

Comment: Does Johnny call it "woman astride"? If so, that could be confusing for someone who's not familiar with that terminology.

Comment: Yes , he called it woman astride .

Comment: she found it confused , is it because astride position doesn't necessarily be on top ?

Comment: I haven't seen the film, so I don't actually **know** but if I had to guess, it's because the term most commonly used in the US is "Girl/woman on top"... "woman astride" may be the "technical term" or the term used by some but it's not necessarily universally understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My reading of the scene was that it was a way of contrasting her sexual experience (great) with her IQ (small). Simply put, although she has plenty of experience "*doin' it on top*", she lacks the vocabulary and the wit to recognise that that's what he's talking about.

Note that she also fails to realise that he's been to prison, imagining that he's been living in a monastery (!?).

---

This quite a common [conceit](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BrainlessBeauty) in Hollywood films and her personality fits quite nicely with the TV. Tropes descriptor:

> The Brainless Beauty is rarely the hero; they tend to be foils for
>   more intelligent (though less successful romantically) characters.
>   Some are sympathetic good-natured dullards, others are presented as
>   annoying obstacles for our heroes. Either way expect a smart but plain
>   character to be left fuming at the unfairness of it all.
>
> A Brainless Beauty — even a sweet-natured one — is unlikely to be the
>   serious love interest of The Hero. In fact they make a natural
>   Romantic False Lead. It can happen though if the Beauty shows some
>   form of Hidden Depths.